# Azure ServiceBus BrokeredMessage body is coming in as null

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a Timer Triggered function that is sending objects to a service bus Topic like this

```cs
        [FunctionName("ProcessTermedEmployee")]
        public static async Task Run(
                        [TimerTrigger("%TimerInterval%"
            #if DEBUG
            , RunOnStartup=true
             #endif
            )] TimerInfo myTimer,
            [ServiceBus("%TermedEmployeeTopicName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<string> termedEmployeeCollector,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("ProcessTermedEmployee Timer function invoked.");
            try
            {
               // var termedEmployees = new List<TermedEmployee>();
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HRSQLConNString")))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("hp_Cdi_Get_Termed_Employees_Recent", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TermedAfterDate", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)));
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                TermedEmployee termedEmployee = ConvertTermedEmployee(rdr);
                              //  termedEmployees.Add(termedEmployee);
                                await 
               
               termedEmployeeCollector.AddAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(termedEmployee));
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ex.Data.Add("row", rdr);
                            log.LogCritical(ex, ex.Message);
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }
                }
                log.LogInformation("ProcessTermedEmployee Timer function finished.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogCritical(ex, ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

then i have a service bus trigger function that is suppose to receive the message and adds it to CosmosDB

```cs
    public static class LogTermedEmployee
    {
        [FunctionName("LogTermedEmployee")]
        public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%TermedEmployeeTopicName%", "%ServiceBusSubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] BrokeredMessage message,
                [CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "%CosmosDbName%",
                collectionName: "%TermedEmployeesLogCollection%",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosConnection")]
                IAsyncCollector<TermedEmployeeLog> termedEmployeesLogCollection,
          ILogger log)
          {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function LogTermedEmployee, 
     processed at {DateTime.Now}");
            try
            {
          
                if(message.GetBody<TermedEmployee>() != null)
                {
                    //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(message.Body);
                  // string s = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(message.Body);
                          var termedEmp =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TermedEmployee> 
              (message.GetBody<string>());
                    await termedEmployeesLogCollection.AddAsync(new TermedEmployeeLog() { 
                   TermedEmployee = termedEmp, DateOfProcess = DateTime.Now, Id = 
                   Guid.NewGuid(), PartitionKey = "TermedEmployee", ModifiedOn = 
                      DateTime.Now, ModifiedBy = "TermedEployeeLogService", MessageId = "" 
               });// message.MessageId });

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                log.LogCritical(ex, ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

```
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="AzureFunctions.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="CDI.Utilities.LogHelpers" Version="0.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="5.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="4.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="4.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
<PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.ServiceBus" Version="6.2.2" />
```

**Problem**

in the ServiceBus trigger's Signature

if I use BrokeredMessage message message.GetBody() is null

if I use Obsoleted Message object then Message.Body is null

but if i use simple string i get the proper Json.

any suggestion please?

Comment: Would you please share what version of the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extension.ServiceBus` package is being used?

Comment: added packages information in the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest changing `BrokeredMessage` to `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` in in your trigger:

```cs
public static async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger(
        "%TermedEmployeeTopicName%", 
        "%ServiceBusSubscriptionName%", 
        Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] 
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
    [CosmosDB(
        databaseName: "%CosmosDbName%",
        collectionName: "%TermedEmployeesLogCollection%",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosConnection")]
        IAsyncCollector<TermedEmployeeLog> termedEmployeesLogCollection,
        ILogger log)
```

I believe that will resolve the binding issue.

**Additional Context**

Starting in v5.0.0, the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` package began using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` internally.  There is no `BrokeredMessage` type in the new package.  Incoming messages are typed as `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`, outgoing messages as `ServiceBusMessage`.

More information can be found in the [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.servicebus-readme).